# How to call method and send ether to it from web3?

Tags: solidity, web3js, polygon

Have this in solidity

```
function claim() public payable nonReentrant {
    ......
    require(mintingFee <= msg.value, "Not Enough Ether Required To Mint");
    ....
}
```

Trying to call it with something like

```
const send = await nftContract.methods.claim().send({from:OWNER_ADDRESS, to:NFT_CONTRACT_ADDRESS, value:web3Instance.utils.toWei("0.001", "ether"),  gasPrice: gasPriceWei});
```

But nothing happens when I call this JS code, just a note I am trying to do this on Matic but should be the same as on Ethereum.

Answer (score 0):

This works properly, just matic was stuck somehow and didnt process trx for few minutes. You can use this without a problem.